# How to get number of hundreds and tens from a total value in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

From excel i am getting number place value using mod operator like this
=MOD(number,place*10) - MOD(number,place)

[image]

Please help how will i get like this in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same in C#, just the syntax is different:

```
public int GetPlace(int value, int place)
{
    return (value % (place*10)) - (value % place);
}
```

See [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BGWBPH) for usage example.
If you just want the digit you can divide it by the place:

```
public int GetPlace(int value, int place)
{
    return ((value % (place * 10)) - (value % place)) / place;
}
```

see [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7W3Fh)

Comment: Thanks for reply, if value is 25000 it is not working, but i need number of hundreds from given value. plz assist

Comment: @krishna Sure it does - at least it does exactly what your example in Excel does (see updated snippet from the link)...